# Django 301 and 403 forbidden errors on my static files in production

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django website on a ubuntu 14.04 vps using nginx and gunicorn but my css files and js files are not getting loaded.i developed it on the default django development server and it worked very well, but when i deploy my site and `collectstatic` and try to access it through the browser only the HTML text gets loaded and on checking on my browser console i find `301` and `403` `forbidden` errors on my static folder. i a newbie to ubuntu and django as well and all the threads and forums i've found online simply point to permissions and ownership of files and haven't had any luck when i correct my permissions.

[screenshot of my browser error when i try to access django admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3mXl.jpg)

here is my settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com','www.mysite.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'powerlineapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'powerlineproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'powerlineproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if not DEBUG: 
    STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/powerline/powerlineproject/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

here is my main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('powerlineapp.urls')),

]
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data www-data;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    include /etc/nginx.custom.events.d/*.conf;
}

http {
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    keepalive_timeout 20;
    client_header_timeout 20;
    client_body_timeout 20;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 20;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include mime.conf;
    charset UTF-8;

    open_file_cache max=100000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    server_tokens off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    include proxy.conf;
    include fcgi.conf;

    include conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx.custom.d/*.conf;
}

include /etc/nginx.custom.global.d/*.conf;
```

my site conf file

```
server {
    listen *:80;



    server_name powerlineagencies.co.ke;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/powerline-agencies.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/powerline-agencies.error.log;

    root /var/www/powerline/powerlineproject;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;





    location  / {



        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/ajenti-v-gunicorn-powerline-agencies-python-wsgi-0.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }


    location ~ /static/.* {
        alias /var/www/powerline/powerlineproject;




    }
```

}

here is my directories structure

[screenshot of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJitT.jpg)

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: show your main urls.py

Comment: updated my question and included my main urls.py, its nothing fancy but i believe that is adequate enough to load my admin dashboard at least. but i'm not sure why it doesn't work in production.

Comment: Are you sure your nginx user `www-data` can access `/var/www/powerline/powerlineproject`. You should try nginx config as ```location /static/ {
        root /var/www/powerline/powerlineproject;
    }```

Comment: if i said im sure id be lying. let me explain what i did so you can give me your correct input. first i created a user with sudo priviledges and the logged i to server with the user account. navigated to `var/www` and created a folder `powerline` then inside the folder i created a virtualenv and activated it and created my django project named powerlineproject, then i edited my `settings.py` and added `STATIC_ROOT`  as advised by @Exprator then made my migrations and collected static..then setup my nginx confs as directed.navigated to the browser and tried to access django admin..still 403 :-(

Comment: did you try the edited ans @gathagu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in ngix

```
location /static/ {    

            alias /var/www/powerline/powerlineproject/static/;    
         }
```

add this lines to urls.py and collectstatic and then check

Comment: i've tried your solution but still no luck. my files are still forbidden.

Comment: are you serving it with any server? like nginx?

Comment: updated my question. i have included both nginx conf files for both my site and the default nginx.conf file.

Comment: i have tried your solution and updated my nginx files but still nothing happened..the errors still remains. :-( .Even tried to reload and restart nginx

Comment: why dont you keep the static root as /static and remove the full path from your settings? and check again by doing collectstatic

Comment: you mean remove the full path on my `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: yup, and keep STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

Comment: I changed the static root to what You specified above and still not getting any change..still 403..can it be a problem with my slashes(/) im not sure how to place them correctly for django to access my static folder

Comment: tell me the path where the static files are created when used collectstatic? @gathagu

Comment: i have added a screenshot of my directory structure.see edit

Comment: I have redone the whole deployment again from scratch and ended up with the same errors.@Exprator including edit above. i really can't figure out where exactly i'm going wrong.

Comment: well i did everything you told me to but now i have a new problem `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://example.com/static/admin/css/base.css/`  thats what im getting on the console now.

Comment: great bro :) hope could help @gathagu

Answer (score 29):

Nginx needs to be able to read the static folder. You can do this by adding the www-data user to the group that your project user is in.

`sudo usermod -a -G your_user www-data`

Then restart nginx.

Comment: this helped me after several hours of searching and debugging!

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed my issue by putting the username (that I am using in the prod server) in `nginx.conf` file.

`nginx.conf` file can be found in this location: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

When I was getting the `403 Forbidden` error, the user section was: `user www-data;`. I had to change that to `user ubuntu;` (as I am using ubuntu user to run my application).

Answer (score 0):

Check your project ownership:
`ls -l <YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER>` and make sure that your user and group are the same as the user you have in `nginx.conf`.

In your case you have `user www-data www-data;`

Answer (score 0):

Check user and group permissions,may be some javascripts does'nt have execute permission.
I mean rwx permisson for static folder and subfolders.